# How do I change the color of the vertical scroll bar on the right side of VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I used a dark theme, but it was too subtle!

[image]

Answer (score 46):

You can [customize your theme colors](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color).

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to bring up the command palette and run the `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)` command. Add the following lines to your configuration:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "scrollbarSlider.background": "#ff0000",
},
```

This will change the scrollbar slider color to red. Adjust the colour value as you like. See more colour options for the scrollbar [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#scrollbar-control).

Comment: I used ``Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)``   Much easier to see now.

Comment: Yes, the  `Preferences: Open JSON Settings` didnt exist on my computer.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, the command name seems to have changed during the VSCode versions. I updated the answer accordingly.